# `trap`-ing Linux Signals - SIGSTOP?

Tags: linux, signals

The Docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) note the following (w/ code) on how to run `clean up` upon a container's shutdown:

> Lastly, if you need to do some extra cleanup ... on shutdown, ..., you
>   may need to ensure that the `ENTRYPOINT` script receives the Unix
>   signals, passes them on, and then does some more work

```
#!/bin/sh

trap "echo TRAPed signal" HUP INT QUIT KILL TERM

/usr/sbin/apachectl start
```

I think that this `trap` will catch a `KILL` signal. However, I read in this [post](https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86#.b8lb7rfrp):

> All signals except for SIGKILL and SIGSTOP can be intercepted by the process.

However, another [post](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0160.php) states:

> There is one signal that you cannot trap: SIGKILL or signal 9.

Which is it?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot catch SIGSTOP. The page you referenced was mistaken.

Yes, the above script tries to catch the KILL signal. It fails. You can verify this yourself quite easily with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Running shell in pid $$"
trap "echo TRAPed signal" HUP INT QUIT KILL TERM STOP

sleep 20
```

Try sending it the KILL and STOP signals, you will see that the process dies and halts, respectively, without the message being printed. If you try any other caught signal, you will see those are handled as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. As an added reference, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#Handling_signals) notes: `There are two signals which cannot be intercepted and handled: SIGKILL and SIGSTOP.`

Comment: @KevinMeredith, if you believe this answered your question, please accept it by clicking the V next to the answer.